# How to send Request only if string matches data

Tags: javascript, jquery, tampermonkey

I would like my script to read the "ident" from the event data and if it matches a specific string. Print "hello" or something like that in console & if the "ident" doesn't matche the specific string. Send the post request.

Here is some of the data printed in a example. https://pastebin.com/ZMck0WsM

```
var evtSource = new EventSource("http://colorillo.com/_watch//_index?_=1559553617984");

evtSource.onmessage = function(e) {
var obj = JSON.parse(e.data);
var line = JSON.stringify(obj.line)

$.post("/draw.php?ing=_index", {
                l: (line),
                w: ("30"),
                c: ("#ffffff"),
                o: ("100"),
                f: ("1"),
                _: ("false")
            })
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?   It should be as easy as looking at line.ident's value, and doing an 'if' conditional around the $.post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try and if the following helps

```
var match = ident.match(/[a-z]/); //remember to put the patten of what you want to match
if(match){
  console.log(match)
}else{
 //send post request
}
```

Comment: Hello. This works as well. I thank you. I now have a issue. ``w: (obj.lineWidth)`` How could i increase the lineWidth by 1 or 2? So what ever that data is, add a value of 1 or 2 to it? I tried ``w: (obj.lineWidth+1)`` but no luck.

Comment: It's like it doubles the value. I just want to increase that value of the obj.lineWidth, plus one. So let's say the value of that object is 5, with the value of 1 being added u know. it'll be 6.

Comment: Try doing `w : parseInt(obj.lineWidth) + valueYouWantToIncreamentWith`

Answer (score 0):

```
if (obj.ident === "foo")
{
    console.log("hello")
}
else
{
    // Send post request...
}
```

Comment: Thanks bud. Just what I needed. The "C" in "console" is caps had to lowercase it but works like a charm.

Comment: I now have a issue. ``w: (obj.lineWidth)`` How could i increase the lineWidth by 1 or 2? So what ever that data is, add a value of 1 or 2 to it? I tried ``w: (obj.lineWidth+1)`` but no luck. I also tried ``var line = JSON.stringify(obj.line) + 2;``

Comment: `obj.lineWidth` is a string in the example data that you linked. To perform math operations on it (like adding 1), you will need to convert it to an int.

Try this: `w: parseInt(obj.lineWidth) + 1`